# Trying to loop through multiple components in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to loop through multiple components in React. Essentially I would like the questions to loop through and transition similarly to the example for Lapsed User on https://iteratehq.com/.

Here is the main page that the components will loop in:

```
import React from 'react';
import Q1Name from './questions/Q1Name';
import Q2Birthday from './questions/Q2Birthday';
import Q3City from './questions/Q3City';
import Q4YouReady from './questions/Q4YouReady';
import Q5Setting from './questions/Q5Setting';
import Q6Length from './questions/Q6Length';
import Q7Email from './questions/Q7Email';



class SignUpPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const questions = [Q1Name, Q2Birthday, Q3City, Q4YouReady, Q5Setting, Q6Length, Q7Email];
        const QList = questions.map(function(question){
            return {question};
        });
        return (
            <div className = "container-fluid">
                <div className = "question-box">
                    <Q1Name />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignUpPage;
```

The below is an example component I would like to bring in - note each question is slightly different. They take in name, email (with validation), city, birthday (date form), and various button answer options.

```
import React from 'react';

class Q1Name extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="questions">
                <h1 id="question-h1">What is your name?</h1>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="name" className="form-control text-form custom-form" id="yourNameHere" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-custom btn-lg" onClick={console.log("hallo")}>Next Question!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Q1Name;
```

I have been able to get everything else working except for this part. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple demo of your requirement. The key is to just create a JSX element (`<Component />`) in a loop and then return the result via the `render` method.

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>I'm A, with {this.props.testProp}</div>;
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>I'm B, with {this.props.testProp}</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const components = [A, B];
    const componentsToRender = components.map((Component, i) => (
      <Component key={i} testProp="testProp"/>
    ));
    return <div>{componentsToRender}</div>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Note the usage of a special `key` prop, when creating components in a loop. I've just used the index in the array for demo purposes, but it's recommended to use something that'll always be unique to that component. More on that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: So that definitely got me much closer!! It is now showing all elements on one page - Is there a trick to loop through them whenever the submit button is clicked.. ie: question 1: fill in name then submit => question 2 - submit => question 3? I assume it requires an onClick function

Comment: You mean you want to re-render all the questions every time a submit button is clicked?

Comment: yes, so essentially the user can only see one question at a time. My end goal is for the questions to transition in each time the next button is clicked.

Comment: One way you can accomplish this is to keep a `currentQuestion` in the state of your `App` component. Then, define a function in `App` which takes an index as a parameter and updates the `currentQuestion` state. Pass down this function as a prop to each of your questions and call it when you want to move to another question. Also, only render the question at the same same index as `currrentQuestion`.

Answer (score 3):

React components are just functions. The JSX syntax is not something special, using `<Component />` will compile to `React.createElement(Component, null)` (`null` because no props are being passed). The only special case are the components starting with lower case letter, for example `<div />`. These compile to `React.createElement("div", null)`. This is true for any string you use, so be careful, `<myCustomComponent />` will still compile into `React.createElement("myCustomComponent", null)`, in turn creating a `myCustomComponent` DOM node, which most likely doesn't exist.

You can apply this knowledge to your case. You're already mapping through the list of your questions, all you need to change is the naming convention and render the questions:

```
const questions = [Q1Name, Q2Birthday, Q3City, Q4YouReady, Q5Setting, Q6Length, Q7Email];
const QList = questions.map(function(Question){
    return (<Question />);
});
```

*Note: I like to add `()` around all the components, just to have some limits between JSX and regular JS code. I'm not sure if it's really needed in this case*.

Alternatively, you can replace the `return` inside your current `map` function with:

```
return React.createElement(question, null);
```

Again, the null is for `props` value. If you want to pass some props, you can do that by passing an object instead of the `null` value. The passed object maps directly to `this.props` values inside the referenced question component. By the way, you can do the same with the above approach `<Question prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} />` will still work the same as it does with any other React component.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely helped a lot. Really appreciate the explanation :)